# What to do when a cat's behavior suddenly changes?

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training

Last night my 6 year old cat was meowing a lot. He then got on a bed in my spare room and defecated right in front of me. I immediately put him outside, but he came straight back indoors. After that, he slept for the night, but again today, he has not been outside.

I'm worried in case this happens again. I put the litter box out so at least he has somewhere other than the bed to do his duty (if he continues not wanting to go outside).  He has urinated and defecated in the litter tray, rather than go outside to do them all day.

Really concerned, as I don't want to be dealing with litter trays again!

Comment: Litter trays aren't such a big deal - Clean it daily/every other day, that's all you have to do. Though I don't know what the question is, I think you want someone to give you an advice regarding how to make your cat urinate etc outside? Please make this clear.

Comment: Assuming the "meowing a lot" and not going outside are unusual behaviour for your cat, he may be ill. I'd take him to the vet ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the "meowing a lot" and not going outside are unusual behaviour for your cat, he may be ill. I'd take him to the vet ASAP.

Also check his body carefully for any tender spots. He may have been bitten. When the skin of a cat is punctured, it can heal quickly, but the flesh underneath can be infected, causing an abscess.

If the vet gives him a clean bill of health, it may be that something outside frightened your cat. See if you can identify the problem and solve it. If it's a dog, perhaps you can make sure your cat has a high place to jump to, or fence the yard. If it's another cat, they will probably sort out the boundary issues themselves, but keep a close eye on the situation.

And if your cat wants to stay inside from now on, consider that indoor cats usually live *much* longer than outdoor cats.

Answer (score -2):

Take him to the vet!! This can be the result of some very serious diseases including cancer. Take him to the vet ASAP!!